# Why am I seeing multi line standard output for what should be a single line writer?

Tags: go

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/gosuri/uilive"
)

var writer = uilive.New()

const kb = 1024.00

func main() {
    writer.Start()
    // start listening for updates and render
    dirSize(os.Args[1])
    writer.Stop()
}

func dirSize(path string) (float64, error) {
    // todo check if path exists
    var size float64
    err := filepath.Walk(path, func(_ string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            size += float64(info.Size())
            fmt.Fprintf(writer, "Size: %f GB\n", size/(kb*kb*kb))

        }
        return err
    })
    return size, err
}
```

You can grab uilive with:

```
go get github.com/gosuri/uilive
```

The code is in $GOPATH/diskusage. When I run it with:

```
go build && ./diskusage "/Users/clint/Music"
```

Here's what it looks like (outputting on multiple lines):

[image]

Here's something like I expected it to look like with the output on the same line:

[image]

The uilive.Writer code looks like it's thread safe:
https://github.com/gosuri/uilive/blob/master/writer.go

I don't understand why it's outputting multiple lines when it should only be writing to a single line.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs for that package state

> [uilive] provides a buffered io.Writer that is flushed at a timed interval.

You're simply writing faster than the output buffer is being flushed. If you want the buffer to be flushed after every write, call `Flush()` after every write.

```
fmt.Fprintf(writer, "Size: %f GB\n", size/(kb*kb*kb))
writer.Flush()
```

Comment: Pshh… that was totally it. Thanks! I'll mark this as accepted. It's saying I have to wait a few minutes. Not sure why.